# Jerky scroll with minimal UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

A barebones app that I created involving tableview is scrolling choppily in the simulator.
I am not able to figure why this is happening. I have worked on iOS6 and before. I am doing this in iOS 9.1

The only relevant code I have in table view is :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.listItems.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuse" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.listItems[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

I have a hunch that it is some issue with simulator or some issue with my mac. But I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: don't you need a registerClass:forReuseIdentifier: call somewhere?

Comment: @Alistra: have given the identifier in xib. (If that was the case it would have crashed right. This is just choppy scrolling)

Comment: are you calling reloadData somewhere?

Comment: Nope. Not calling it.